CYGWIN ERROR: cc1: fatal error: No such file or directory
i'm new to programming and it's my first time using CYGWIN. I used Notepad++ to create my code, named the file "lab1exe_A.c" but when i try to run it using the CYGWIN terminal this error message keeps popping up : "cc1: fatal error: lab1exe_A.c No such file or directory
compilation terminated."
I've looked up a few solutions, removing spaces in the name, but didn't seem to work. I've considered downloading more packages but i didn't know which ones in particular so i've scrapped that idea. I'm really confused and desperatelyy needs help.

In cygwin terminal, enter the command ls . do you see the file you want to compile  ?

btw, just for clarity, it looks like you have a c file extension, which is not a file that can "run", it first needs to be compiled to create a runnable executable.


when entering the command ls , i don't see the file.  2. how would i compile said file into and executable one?


You'll first need to find the location of your code and tell cygwin terminal to go there. This Q&A Using Cygwin to Compile a C program; Execution error should describe how get your cygwin terminal to navigate to the directory of your c file. That same question also shows how to use gcc to compile your code.

i just looked up a few solutions and try to reproduce it but this error message: "-bash: cd/cygdrive/c/Users/aroln/Documents: No such file or directory" or some variation of it keeps popping up

How about try the root first , cd /cygdrive/, then ls do you see c drive listed? if not check the Cygwin Tutorials and FAQs to configure your Cygwin environment https://cygwin.com/faq.html
